# jQuery.ajax() in node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

Is it possible to use `jQuery.ajax()` in node.js exactly as it is syntax-wise?

I am trying to share non-UI browser code with node.js. I do not want to replace all the existing function calls with my own wrapper.

Currently when I try it, it would say "No Transport" by default because jQuery does domain detection. If I turn it off by setting `jQuery.support.cors` it would say XMLHttpRequest.open() not available.

Comment: Overriding the Ajax method of jQuery with a small HTTP client in Node would be a better option than replacing all existing calls in the code, but still hacky.

Comment: [#380](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/380) references this issue. Just updated my [nq](https://npmjs.org/package/nq) package to workaround this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was able to solve the "No Transport" issue using the XMLHttpRequest module, like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
};
```

Answer (score 12):

also consider najax, a wrapper for the node request module which allows jquery style syntax for server-side requests

https://github.com/alanclarke/najax

```
var najax = require('najax');
najax('http://www.google.com', function(html){ console.log(html); });
najax('http://www.google.com', { type:'POST' }, function(html){ console.log(html); });
najax({ url:'http://www.google.com', type:'POST', success: function(html){ console.log(html); });
najax({ url:'http://www.google.com', type:'POST' }).success(function(resp){}).error(function(err){});

najax.get, najax.post, najax.put, najax.delete...
```

Comment: This lead me to [jajax](https://npmjs.com/jajax.js) and [djax](https://npmjs.com/djax) which have no dependencies (particularly the bulky lodash) making them better suited for browserify projects.

Comment: I eventually ended up not finding a jQuery.ajax equivalent that suited my needs. `djax` doesn't support the quite convenient `complete` handler, so I decided to go with future technology: https://github.com/github/fetch

Answer (score 8):

If you want the exact jQuery.ajax syntax, try https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest

But really if you have control over what you're calling ajax for, you should do it with node's `http.request` or a module like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

Comment: It is not as intuitive as I had though. The [node jquery](http://search.npmjs.org/#/jquery) module has built-in support for [node-XMLHttpRequest](http://search.npmjs.org/#/xmlhttprequest). However, it has been broken by recent version of jsdom.

Comment: @voidvector: you are right, jsdom now defines a "noop" `XMLHttpRequest` function as referenced here: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/380

Answer (score 7):

I am also sharing code between a browser and nodejs and also use JQuery for Ajax calls. JQuery requires a window which I use from domino.

update:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
{
  if (typeof global !== 'undefined' && typeof global.process !== 'undefined' &&
    Object.prototype.toString.call(global.process) === '[object process]') {
    var domino = require('domino');
    var window = domino.createWindow('<html></html>');

    var document = window.document;
    var $ = require('jquery')(window);
    var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
    $.support.cors = true; // cross domain, Cross-origin resource sharing
    $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you exporting "huepi" when its not defined anywhere?

Comment: Good point :). I copied it from my project that uses this, It is called huepi: https://github.com/arndbrugman/huepi. I'll remove it from the code above. Thx for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/), it allows hybrid browserjs and nodejs.

Before, I tried to use canvas2d in nodejs, but finally I gave up. It's not supported by nodejs default, and too hard to install it (many many ... dependeces).
Until I use Electron, I can easily use all my previous browserjs code, even WebGL, and pass the result value(eg. result base64 image data) to nodejs code.