# Refresh_token using oauth.io

Tags: node.js, oauth

Hi I am student of Computer Science and doing some experiments on oauth.io. but i am facing problem to get refresh_token after getting code successfully. After getting the code i am writing the follwing line of code but its giving me Internal server error..

The code is

```
$.ajax("https://oauth.io/auth/access_token", {
    type: "post",
    data: {
        code: result.code,
        key: '5WeOrrR3tP6RyShR1',
        secret: '2_q3tb_D_qgDwSGpt' },
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log("result", data); 
    }   
});
```

Which url used to get refresh_token? please someone help me.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there was a bug recently in the js sdk when you set the response type server-side (to get the code & refresh_token), so you may have to redownload oauth.js if you use a static version.

I guess your jquery code is server side (because of the nodejs tag and the use of a code), but i had an error "no transport" that [i fixed with a new XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638820/jquery-ajax-in-node-js). Here is my full test:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
var win = jsdom().createWindow();
var $ = require('jquery')(win);
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
    return new XMLHttpRequest;
}

$.ajax("https://oauth.io/auth/access_token", {
    type: "post",
    data: {
        code: process.argv[2],
        key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret: 'yyyyyyyyyyyy' },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("result", data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error(arguments);
    }
});
```

and my result looks like:

```
{ access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  request:
   { url: '{{instance_url}}',
     required: [ 'instance_url' ],
     headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer {{token}}' } },
  refresh_token: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy',
  id: 'https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Db0000000ZbGGEA0/005b0000000SSGXAA4',
  instance_url: 'https://eu2.salesforce.com',
  signature: 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz',
  state: 'random_string',
  provider: 'salesforce' }
```

Comment: i am using Asp.ne on server side and its working and returning me responce is this {
    "oauth_token": "1855088594-6LmvjMTafZsaAunQ9t0nSoSk67ukd4g46r7MIIv",
    "oauth_token_secret": "LMwCeKQV3Ldz1r0zXddUZAZw0M1ZkIwSIYC6J3XU",
    "request": {
        "url": "https://api.twitter.com"
    },
    "state": {
        "oauthio_state": "wapizbilal.bsse986@gmail.com"
    },
    "provider": "twitter"
}

Comment: there is no refresh_token in this responce

Comment: twitter does not provide any refresh token since their tokens does not expire (i think it is still the case). btw, you should not post your tokens on SO

Comment: Thanks i understand and now its working and i am happy actually i am using this library in my final year project. now i will install opensource version of oauthd daemon... thanks very much Mr.bumpmann