# Ajax with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

i know some persons asked this question before but i don't understand answers :/
I'm using node.js, and i realy want to use Ajax in it.
My code is :

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
var http = require("http");
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
var fs = require("fs");
var colors = require('colors');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 fs.createReadStream("index.php").pipe(res)
}).listen(8080)
// ###################################################################################################################################
// ########################################################## CLASSE SERVER ##########################################################
// ###################################################################################################################################
var tableauDeJoueur = new Array();

var server = ws.createServer(function (connection){
 connection.nickname = null
 connection.on("text", function (str){
  if (connection.nickname === null){
   connection.nickname = str;
   
   console.log((connection.nickname+" arrive sur PixelWorld !").green);
  }
  else{
   var code = str.substring(0,2);
   var reste = str.substring(2,str.length);
   switch(code){
    case "01":
     var coupe = reste.split("4H[m~Ft7");
     var mail = coupe[0];
     var mdp = coupe[1];
     $.ajax({
      url: "fonctionPHP/connection.php",    
      type: "POST",
      data: {'mail': mail,'mdp': mdp},
      async:false,
      success: function(html){
       if(html == "OK"){
        console.log("oui");
       }
       else{
        console.log("non");
       }
      }
     });
     break;
    case "02":
     break;
   }
  }
 })
 connection.on("close", function (){
  console.log((connection.nickname+" a quitté PixelWorld !").red);
 })
})
server.listen(8081)

function broadcast(str) {
 server.connections.forEach(function (connection) {
  connection.sendText(str)
 })
}
```

My problem is at the line "$.ajax({".
The server notice me when a user is coming, it's ok. But when he send a message with a 01 code, node crash and say me :

```js
 $.ajax({
                                          ^
TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
                                if ( !w.document ) {
                                        throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                                }
                                return factory( w );
                        } has no method 'ajax'
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/www/dhkuhnuhbnkiuh/app.js:46:8)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Connection.processFrame (/var/www/dhkuhnuhbnkiuh/node_modules/nodejs-websocket/Connection.js:516:9)
    at Connection.extractFrame (/var/www/dhkuhnuhbnkiuh/node_modules/nodejs-websocket/Connection.js:458:14)
    at Connection.doRead (/var/www/dhkuhnuhbnkiuh/node_modules/nodejs-websocket/Connection.js:209:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/dhkuhnuhbnkiuh/node_modules/nodejs-websocket/Connection.js:52:8)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
```

Sorry if my English isn't good, I'm French and bad at English. :/
Thank you for your help :D

Comment: See this : https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery could be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a request from `nodejs` is fairly easy, dont have to use `$.ajax` at all. You can use the npm [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module. `$.ajax` is built for firing requests from the browser. But if you 'really' want to use `$.ajax` on `node`, I think you can read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638820/jquery-ajax-in-node-js)

Comment: So if i understand, you say me i don't need Ajax, because "request" can do what i need ? I'm i right ?

Comment: Yes! You dont need to use JQuery on your server side code, it was mainly build for DOM manipulations and to make browser side UI tasks easy. The npm package `request` will provide you with the necessary functions you need.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! Need i to close the project ? How can i thanks you on this website ?

Comment: Yes, it's working, i think it need to have an http link ;/ Thank you so much :D

Comment: I am not sure about accessing a relative path to a php file from nodejs. I dont know php. If the ajax problem is solved, and if my answer was of any help, then please upvote and mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

First,we begin with understanding AJAX and Node.Ajax is a client-side xml-based technology that automatically updates contents of a web page, without the page having to reload. Node.js is a server-side scripting language.
To illustrate this clearly, we will create a client `client.html` file and a server `server.js`
Aside from having npm installed, we will install `express` middleware and some of it's dependencies that we are going to use.
`npm install --save express body-parser body-parser-xml`

Let's begin by writing our `server.js` file. This file is going to parse xml requests sent AJAX. After processing request body, server should then send response back to client.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);

app.use(bodyParser.xml({
  limit: '1MB',
  XmlParseOptions: {
    normalize: true,
    normalizeTags: true,
    explicitArray: false
  }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "client.html");
});

app.post('/library', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var title = req.body.book.title;
  var author = req.body.book.author;
  var year = req.body.book.year;
  console.log(title + " " + author + " " + year);
  //optional operations like database can be performed here
  // we are sending a response mimicking a successfull search query
  res.end("Book Found in library");
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  var host = '127.0.0.1';
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Server running at http://%s:%s\n", host, port);
});
```

Next, create `client.html` file. This file will have simple form that when submitted call on an AJAX function that in turn sends xml data to `server.js` then waits and process response

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Search() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
      xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/library', true);

      console.log(document.getElementById('title').value);
      console.log(document.getElementById('author').value);

      var text = "<book>" +
        "<title>" + document.getElementById('title').value + "</title>" +
        "<author>" + document.getElementById('author').value + "</author>" +
        "<year>" + document.getElementById('year').value + "</year>" +
        "</book>";

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log("All ok. You hit the server");
          }
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
      xmlhttp.send(text);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="" method="POST" action="">
  Title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
  Author:<input type="text" name="author" id="author">
  Year:<input type="text" name="year" id="year"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this guide helps in future. Thanks