# Beginning jquery on node, how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, node.js

For the following sample:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
$.ajax({url : 'https://api.github.com/orgs/foo/members'})
    .then(function(members) {
        for (var i in members) {
            $.ajax({url : 'https://api.github.com/users/' + members[i].login})
                .then(function(member) {
                    console.log(member.name)
                });
        }
    });
```

I get this

```
$.ajax({url : 'https://api.github.com/orgs/foo/members'})
  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (sample.js:2:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.## Heading ##js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

No idea how to fix. Any help?

[Notice that code in this answer is not helping me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916217/1000282) I get the same
errors or stuff like `TypeError: Cannot set property 'cors' of undefined`.

1 - I DON'T want advice for why I'm using jquery with node. I have a reason for this, I'm coding in Vim, want to easily test code that will be almost identical to what I'll put in the BROWSER. If you can provide a link for a tutorial for this kind of usage of node, I'd be glad (I've done this before in some remote time, both with node and Rhino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jsdom (can't recall what I used before):

- `npm install jsdom`
- `npm install xmlhttprequest`

---

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env("", ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"], function(err, window) {
    var $ = window.$
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({url : 'https://api.github.com/orgs/foo/members'})
        .then(function(members) {
            for (var i in members) {
                $.ajax({url : 'https://api.github.com/users/' + members[i].login})
                    .then(function(member){
                        console.log(member.name)
                    });
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is an HTTP request made by the browser.  Node is not running your JavaScript inside a browser.  You want to  use Node's [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library to make your HTTP request.

If you feel you have to use jQuery's `.ajax()` function, then [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916217/3814042).

Comment: Sorry, but `$.ajax()` is meant to do AJAX requests.  Node is not run in a browser and so it needs to make normal HTTP requests, not AJAX requests.  The problem isn't that `$.ajax()` is bad practice.  The problem is that you are not making an AJAX request.

Comment: It doesn't matter when there's a module/lib to hide that just for sake of emulating the browser environment.