# Stubbing jQuery.ajax in node environment (jQuery 2.x)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to run some tests that require stubbing `jQuery.ajax`. I'm using SinonJS to do that and it used to work fine with older version of jQuery (1.x)

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var sinon = require("sinon");
sinon.stub($, "ajax"); // this worked because $.ajax is defined
```

However, after upgrading to jQuery 2.x, I have had to include a window environment when I require jquery from my module for it to run. I am using `jsdom` to accomplish this:

```
var document = require('jsdom').jsdom(),
    window  = document.parentWindow,
    $       = require('jquery')(window);
```

**PROBLEM** `$.ajax` is now undefined. I suspect because now it returns the jQuery object bound to a specific element but not entirely sure. Does anyone know why and how to get around this?

**EDIT** A buddy of mine who isn't on SO has pointed out that if we attach `window` to global, we can get the plain jquery object instead of the factory

```
    global.window = require('jsdom').jsdom().parentWindow;
    var $ = require('jquery'); // this works as $.ajax is now defined
```

I'm not a fan of attaching window to global as it will affect up some of the plugins which type check window. Not a blocker, but I'd love to see if there is any other way to go around this problem.

Comment: JSDom works with io.js and not "deprecated" environments (like node) so maybe an update of your backend will solve it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'd love to be I have to stick with node for now. I pin `jsdom` to 3.x so that shouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8916217/1348195 ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did. The question has `$.ajax` defined. It's just not working. I don't have this function bound to my jQuery object.

Comment: Why did you want to use jquery ajax ? [Request](https://github.com/request/request) is easier.

Comment: I am testing client code not server code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could have sworn that after reading jquery source, I tried this on the day I asked the question but it didn't work. I tried again just now and it's working.

tl;dr jQuery attaches $ to the window namespace for browser emulator.

```
var document    = require('jsdom').jsdom(),
    window      = document.parentWindow;
require('jquery')(window);
var $ = window.$;
```

Hopefully it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 7):

While Stubs are nice, they are not as good as Fakes which are not as good as Mocks. I would advise using the more intriguing features of ***Sinon*** to create Fakes.

Rather than stubbing the `window.$`, you can fake the `XMLHttpRequest` and or `XMLHttpResponse`

```
var xhr, requests;

before(function () {
    xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
    requests = [];
    xhr.onCreate = function (req) { requests.push(req); };
});

after(function () {
    // Like before we must clean up when tampering with globals.
    xhr.restore();
});

it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
    getTodos(42, sinon.spy());

    assert.equals(requests.length, 1);
    assert.match(requests[0].url, "/todo/42/items");
});
```

Or you can even mock a server

```
var server;

before(function () { server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); });
after(function () { server.restore(); });

it("calls callback with deserialized data", function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();
    getTodos(42, callback);

    // This is part of the FakeXMLHttpRequest API
    server.requests[0].respond(
        200,
        { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, text: "Provide examples", done: true }])
    );

    assert(callback.calledOnce);
});
```

You can get very creative, Mocking timeouts, delays, ***404's***, ***401's***. Because you will still be using the `JQuery.Ajax` object library, while injecting spies that augment requests and responses, you can create more authentic and robust tests with less effort than if you had to stub all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! I do use fake and mock server elsewhere in the code. For simpler tests, I just stub them away. Faster that way :)

Comment: @LimH., ahaa. In that case, my answer is unnecessary. Your need was just syntactical.

Comment: to be fair, the question was a bit badly written. I has nothing to do with stubbing in Sinon and everything to do with how jQuery has changes its export interface in 2.x :D But I really appreciate you taking the time to write your answer. And it does solve the problem although not in a way I was looking for ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices to do requests in node:

1) With jquery

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);
// now $.ajax works well
```

2) With npm request
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

3) Using native object XHR

I test these three options and finally I used package request (to avoid extra packages like jquery + jsdom) and for strange cases native XHR.

Comment: Hey thanks but I am testing client code using tools that run on node. I am not testing server code. Also your choice 1 is wrong. please read the question