# Load jQuery into Mocha test for React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I've created a Mocha test setup similar to this tutorial outlined here: https://github.com/jesstelford/react-testing-mocha-jsdom.

I'm wondering how I can load in jQuery into this structure. I've included it as `require('jquery')` test JS file, but when I call `$.ajax`, it gives an error saying `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property ajax as function`. I suspect that this is because Node is not running my JavaScript inside a browser. However, I've tried using a [window environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945046/stubbing-jquery-ajax-in-node-environment-jquery-2-x), but still no luck.

I know the traditional way is to include jQuery in HTML  tags, but I'm not sure how to do that here, since I don't have an HTML file.

Comment: are you doing `var $ = require('jquery');`?

Comment: @PhilVarg Yup, I'm doing exactly that.

Comment: @PhilVarg Sorry, the error message was actually a bit different - I updated it with the correct one.

Comment: Might I ask why you've chosen to include jQuery in the first place? Is it just for the ajax requests? If so, using the fetch API polyfill will save your users quite a lot of of downloaded bytes. Unless you have to support older browsers like IE8 there's really no good reason to use jQuery any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pattern that has worked for me for certain jquery methods in mocha, I'm not sure it'll work for ajax but give it a shot and let me know.

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom'
import _$ from 'jquery'

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
global.window = global.document.defaultView
const $ = _$(global.window)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! May I ask how you structured your test code? I have them all in one file.

Comment: @frogbandit this is a good example of structuring your test files https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedReduxCode/tree/master/testing/test