# Sinon FakeServer no requests?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I'm following the SinonJS [Fake Server tutorial](http://sinonjs.org/) and I'm running this simple code:

```
var server;

before(function () { server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); });
after(function () { server.restore(); });

it("calls callback with deserialized data", function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();
    getTodos(42, callback);

    // This is part of the FakeXMLHttpRequest API
    server.requests[0].respond(
        200,
        { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, text: "Provide examples", done: true }])
    );

    assert(callback.calledOnce);
});
```

I'm including the getTodos function in the same file. Here it is as well:

```
function getTodos(listId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
         url: "/todo/" + listId + "/items",
         success: function (data) {
             // Node-style CPS: callback(err, data)
             callback(null, data);
         }
    });
}
```

However, I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'respond' of undefined`. It looks like `server.requests` is empty -- why is this? How can I make sure the requests show up?

**UPDATE**: I was able to narrow down the issue. I added an "error" callback to the getTodos function, and did console.log for the error. It turns out there's a Syntax error coming from the jsdom node module trying to do `urlObj = new URL(uri, documentBaseURLSerialized(this._ownerDocument));` which is then causing `$.ajax({` to fail. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: It looks like you just copied the example word for word. Can't imagine what's wrong.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I think it may be an issue with how I'm getting jQuery. How do you normally import it into a file like this?

Comment: Hmm you may be right. I'll look into one of my projects where I have tests like that in a bit.

Comment: Still looks more or less right, but indeed not having jquery loaded might be a problem.  What happens if you console.log($)  in getTodos?

Comment: @RobertMoskal It returns a large function, so there's definitely something there.

Comment: I'm importing jQuery like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869307/load-jquery-into-mocha-test-for-react-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114967/discussion-between-frogbandit-and-robert-moskal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one issue I can think of is that you did not load Sinon in your JSDom instance. Here is a test file that works here:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var assert = require("assert");

var vc = jsdom.createVirtualConsole();
vc.on("log", console.log.bind(console.log));
vc.on("jsdomError", function jsdomError(er) {
    throw er;
});

var window;
var $;
var sinon;
before(function (done) {
    jsdom.env({
        html: "",
        scripts: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                  "node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js"],
        features: {
            ProcessExternalResources: ["script"],
            FetchExternalResources: ["script", "link"],
        },
        virtualConsole: vc,
        done: function _done(error, w) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            window = w;
            $ = w.$;
            sinon = w.sinon;
            done();
        },

    });
});


function getTodos(listId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
         url: "/todo/" + listId + "/items",
         success: function (data) {
             // Node-style CPS: callback(err, data)
             callback(null, data);
         }
    });
}

var server;

before(function () { server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); });
after(function () { server.restore(); });

it("calls callback with deserialized data", function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();
    getTodos(42, callback);

    // This is part of the FakeXMLHttpRequest API
    server.requests[0].respond(
        200,
        { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, text: "Provide examples", done: true }])
    );

    assert(callback.calledOnce);
});
```

Comment: A bit verbose, but it works! Thank you. I thought just doing `var sinon = require('sinon');` was enough.

Comment: Now I'm trying to test a function in another React component (different file) and I'm running into this same error. I'm quite sure that I loaded Sinon into my JSDom instance. Do you know what's going wrong?

Comment: Asking a new question is the thing to do. The community does not see in a good light answerable questions being modified after they've been answered. I see you've already asked a new question. I've rolled back your edit to your question here because, as per Stack Overflow editorial practices, it does not belong here. I'll look at your new question.