# JSON format when using Marketo REST API to create Custom Object record

Tags: jquery, json, rest, marketo

I'm trying to create a custom object record using the rest API, but I am not sure what my JSON object should look like. I have two fields I need to dedupe (`personID` and `emailAddress`) and then few fields (`question01, question02`)

Looking here I can see where to send the JSON, but I don't understand what the format should look like. I'll be posting the data using jQuery's ajax function
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Custom_Objects/syncCustomObjectsUsingPOST

I also don't understand when or how to get a new token. Maybe that should be for another thread though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing first**:
Unless you are using [jQuery under node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8638820/3897122), you won't be able to use client side javascript to access Marketo REST API, as these requests will be blocked due to CORS.
Also, your `Client Secret` needed to generate an `Access Token` would not remain secret any more at the client side. So, you have to do this from your server.

**The payload**:
The payload in question is better documented under the [REST API / Lead Database / Custom Objects](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/custom-objects/#create_and_update) section of the API documentation.
In your case it would look something like this:

```
{
    'action'    : 'createOrUpdate',// optional
    'dedupeBy'  : 'dedupeFields',// optional
    // input is an array of objects containing the custom object fields
    'input'     : [
        {
            'personID'      : 'personID',
            'emailAddress'  : 'emailAddress',
            'question01'    : 'question01 value',
            'question02'    : 'question02 value'
        },
        // …Other items…
    ]
}
```

which should be in the *body* of the request. The sample code below is an illustration how you would do it with jQuery, but again, it won't work from the client side.

```
var instanceId = '123-ABC-456',
    accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    customObjectName = 'customObjectName_c',
    payload = payloadFromAbove;

$.ajax({
    // Constructing url with ES6 String Interpolation
    url: `https://${instanceId}.mktorest.com/rest/v1/customobjects/${customObjectName}.json?access_token=${accessToken}`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```